# can we implement innerjoin in the following sql query

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2005

These are my tables:

```
CREATE TABLE forgerock (id INT, [date] DATETIME, empcode INT,[file] VARCHAR);
INSERT INTO forgerock
VALUES
    (1, '2015-12-31 01:20:02', 56, 'abc1'),
    (2, '2016-01-01 01:20:02', 58, 'abc2'),
    (3, '2016-01-02 01:20:02', 46, 'abc3'),
    (4, '2016-01-03 01:20:02', 16, 'abc4'),
    (5, '2016-01-04 01:20:02', 36, 'abc5');

CREATE TABLE forge (empcode INT, [user_name] VARCHAR);
INSERT INTO forge
VALUES
    (56, 'ram'),
    (58, 'ram1'),
    (46, 'ram2'),
    (16, 'ram3'),
    (36, 'ram4');
```

I am trying to print the file name and user_name from the tables with respect to current date and the day before the current date.

I tried the query:

```
ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("select file  from forgerock where '"+date+"' >= CURRENT_DATE('"+date+"', INTERVAL 1 DAY);") ;
```

but I got the exception:

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'CURRENT_DATE'.

Comment: `CURRENT_DATE` is not a function that takes an argument.

Comment: Use [datediff](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/func_datediff_mysql.asp)

Comment: Given that today is the 4th, what would the desired result look like?

Comment: all the files from 4th and 3rd should be printed

Comment: What does this question have to do with inner joins as mentioned in the subject?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since am using ms sql the code should be the following way

```
 SELECT fr.file, f.user_name FROM forgerock fr inner join forge f on fr.empcode = f.empcodewhere [date] >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE()-1),0)
```

which will result in printing the two tables file from forgerock and user_name from forge

Answer (score 2):

```
IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.forgerock', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.forgerock

CREATE TABLE dbo.forgerock (id INT PRIMARY KEY, [date] DATETIME, empcode INT,[file] VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO dbo.forgerock
VALUES
    (1, '2015-12-31 01:20:02', 56, 'abc1'),
    (2, '2016-01-01 01:20:02', 58, 'abc2'),
    (3, '2016-01-02 01:20:02', 46, 'abc3'),
    (4, '2016-01-03 01:20:02', 16, 'abc4'),
    (5, '2016-01-04 01:20:02', 36, 'abc5');

IF OBJECT_ID('dbo.forge', 'U') IS NOT NULL
    DROP TABLE dbo.forge

CREATE TABLE dbo.forge (empcode INT PRIMARY KEY, [user_name] VARCHAR(10));
INSERT INTO dbo.forge
VALUES (56, 'ram'),(58, 'ram1'),(46, 'ram2'),(16, 'ram3'),(36, 'ram4')

DECLARE @dt DATETIME = FLOOR(CAST(GETDATE() AS FLOAT))

SELECT *
FROM dbo.forge
WHERE empcode IN (
        SELECT f.empcode
        FROM dbo.forgerock f
        WHERE f.[date] BETWEEN DATEADD(DAY, -1, @dt) AND @dt
    )
```

output -

```
empcode     user_name
----------- ----------
16          ram3
```

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT fr.file, f.user_name 
FROM forgerock fr inner join forge f on fr.empcode = f.empcode
WHERE fr.date >= DATE_ADD(NOW(), INTERVAL -1 DAY)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use datediff to get the difference between two dates.
Try this :

```
ResultSet resultset = statement.executeQuery("select file  from forgerock where DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), '" + date + "') >= 1") ;
```

To test the query use this one :

```
SELECT * FROM forgerock WHERE DATEDIFF(day, GETDATE(), @date) >= 1;
```

Just replace the @date with the value you want, for example '2016-01-02'

Answer (score 0):

Use this filter:

```
SELECT [file]
FROM forgerock 
WHERE [date] >= DATEADD(DAY, DATEDIFF(DAY,0,GETDATE()-1),0)
```

The `DATEADD` expression above will always return 12:00am yesterday morning, allowing your query to only return records from yesterday or today.

*Bonus Tip: avoid using reserved keywords (such as `file` and `date`) as column or table names.*

Comment: its working..but i need to print the files of today's date too along with yesterdays date

Comment: The `>=` operator should be doing that already ... are you doing something other than what I posted?

Answer (score -1):

You have to try following query:-

```
SELECT fr.file, f.user_name 
FROM forgerock fr inner join forge f on fr.empcode = f.empcode
AND `date' >= (DATE_ADD(`date`, INTERVAL 1 day))
```

Comment: i am using ms sql2005...when i given this query i got an exception--com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '1'.

Comment: exception--com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '?'.

Comment: i am not getting an idea of query to be used in ms sql..can any one suggest an idea